# Excel cell formatting to fill color

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm doing some excel formatting, with below formula being used:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(E23),ISBLANK(E24),ISBLANK(E25)),"Section Incomplete","Section Complete")
```

Basically, When the cells `E23`, `E24` and `E25` are filled then a cell will prompt a message "Section Complete" otherwise, either of cells is blank then "Section Incomplete".

What I want to do is, When it is "Section Complete", the background fill of the cell should be Green and when Incomplete, has to be Red.

Please advise if you have any ideas.

Comment: take a look at [Chip Pearson (Excel MVP legend) / cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm) and [Debra Dalglish (Excel MVP Legend) / Contextures.com)](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cell with the IF condition is `E26`, then you'll need to go to

1. Conditional Formatting found in the Home tab
2. New Rule
3. Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4. In the text box enter `=if(E26="Section Complete, 1, 0)`
5. Click Format
6. Click Fill and select the green color you want

Repeat this process for "Section Incomplete" with a new rule on the same cell.

The above is assuming you want to have the text "Section Complete/Incomplete" in the cell. In case you don't then just put your formula as the rule:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(E23),ISBLANK(E24),ISBLANK(E25)),1,0)
```

Set this to red. And

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(E23),ISBLANK(E24),ISBLANK(E25)),0,1)
```

Set this to green.